maximum() function does not work?
I am trying to extract the maximum value from the layer by using Extract by expression tool and maximum() function. Once I type the function in expression dialog window, it shows that system does find the maximum value, but after I press Run it gives back the same layer with all the features inside. So my question, am I doing something wrong?



What you want is to extract only the maximum value.
So you need to put

”NUMPOINTS“ = maximum(“NUMPOINTS“)

In this case, it will select and extract the line that has the NUMPOINTS containing the maximum value.

You're not using that expression to select anything.  If you want only the feature with the maximum "NUMPOINTS", you need to compare the feature "NUMPOINTS" to the maximum "NUMPOINTS".
e.g.
"NUMPOINTS" = maximum("NUMPOINTS")


The other answers are providing the solution to fix the problem. Here I will explain why it is currently selecting all records:
The expression must evaluate to a boolean: true or false, 0 or .... not 0. Usually it is 1 but in your case it is 756, i.e. the maximum value of the field. Since no feature value (only a constant value from the layer) is used the expression is true for every record, and they are therefore all extracted.
